# Traveling Salesman Problem with additional partial ordering

Tags: algorithm, graph, traveling-salesman, topological-sort

I am looking for a **name for this problem** or any leads on an **algorithm or source code**:

Example:  You want to find the best route to visit the 100 largest cities in the US (classic TSP) but before you can visit any given city you must visit the capital of the state it is in.

Example:  You are collecting permission slips from the students of several professors.  You need to visit every student and every professor but you can't visit a professor until you have seen all of his students.

Some Googling turns up the *sequential ordering problem* or "SOP" but there is not so much literature that I am convinced that this is a widely accepted name.

I don't think these partial orderings can be represented within the classic TSP simply by choosing which edges to use in the graph (e.g. you can't initially go from New York to Chicago, but once you visit Springfield you *can*) or weights, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Sequential Ordering Problem* was first introduced by Escudero in 1988 in a paper entitled "*An Inexact Algorithm for the Sequential Ordering Problem*" (this appeared in the European Journal of Operational Research), so this is the original name for the problem. The abstract of the paper reads:

> Given the directed G= (N, A) and the
>   penalty matrix C, the Sequential
>   Ordering Problem (hereafter, SOP)
>   consists of finding the permutation of
>   the nodes from the set N, such that it
>   minimizes a C-based function and does
>   not violate the precedence
>   relationships given by the set A.
>   Strong sufficient conditions for the
>   infeasibility of a SOP's instance are
>   imbedded in a procedure for the SOP's
>   preprocessing. Note that it is one of
>   the key steps in any algorithm that
>   attempts to solve SOP. By dropping the
>   constraints related to the precedence
>   relationships, SOP can be converted in
>   the classical Asymmetric Traveling
>   Salesman Problem (hereafter, ATSP).
>   The algorithm obtains (hopefully)
>   satisfactory solutions by modifying
>   the optimal solution to the related
>   Assignment Problem (hereafter, AP) if
>   it is not a Feasible Sequential
>   Ordering (hereafter, FSO). The new
>   solution 'patches' the subtours (if
>   any) giving preference to the patches
>   with zero reduced cost in the linking
>   arcs. The AP-based lower bound on the
>   optimal solution to ATSP is tightened
>   by using some of the procedures given
>   in [1]. In any case, a local search
>   for improving the initial FSO is
>   performed; it uses 3- and 4-change
>   based procedures. Computational
>   results on a broad set of cases are
>   reported.

Escudero and his collaborators have a number of papers on the subject, with references to even more. Searching for papers by him or that reference this paper may help you if you're looking through the literature.

SOP is a well-studied constrained version of the *Asymmetric Travelling Salesman Problem*, so much of the literature on ATSP may be related.

Comment: Thanks for that history.  I am surprised to see any problem whose roots aren't in work from the 60's or earlier!

Answer (score 0):

You could build a state machine that takes into account the ordering requirements, annotate the transitions with your weights, and solve the traveling salesman on that. Except you'd have a lot more nodes: 2^(number of capitals) times the original number of nodes.